# Is there a possibility to automatically eject an USB C Hub (entire hub) when closing MacBook Pro (M1) Lid?

Tags: macos, mac, usb-c, usb-hub

Is there a way/program/script to automatically eject a USB-C Hubs when closing the lid of a MacBook? Unfortunately, my USB-C Hub draws power when closing my MacBook Pro Lid. When I forget to unplug my USB-C Hub, my MacBook battery is completely drained

Comment: [Unfortunately it seems that this is not possible on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236580/turn-off-usb-power-on-os-x-mac-mini).

Comment: ohh to bad but thanks!